# Azure- zip push deployment for a function app doesn't work

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to update the code in my `App Function` from the CLI using the kudu zip push deployment for a function app.
I am using this command-

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip --name funcApp1 --resource-group MyGroup --src C:\Users\user\Documents\funcApp1.zip
```

And getting this output-

```
Getting scm site credentials for zip deployment Starting zip deployment. This operation can take a while to complete ... Deployment endpoint responded with status code 202
```

It looks like it worked but I can't see the updated code in the `App Function` from the CLI.
What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your files need to be in the root of the zip file with no directory above

your files currently live in the folder *app* which won't work

Answer (score 0):

facing the same issue and I am using below command

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g clitesting4 -n zeroclitrigger --src D:\latestcli\functionapp.zip --build-remote true
```

I think it is related to either a folder structure or some file missing issue as my runtime is python I am using below folder structure.

```
__app__
 | - MyFirstFunction
 | | - __init__.py
 | | - function.json
 | | - example.py
 | - MySecondFunction
 | | - __init__.py
 | | - function.json
 | - SharedCode
 | | - myFirstHelperFunction.py
 | | - mySecondHelperFunction.py
 | - host.json
 | - requirements.txt
 tests
```

all the files I got from vscode . I am not using any **ARM template**

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for us is without using azure pipelines is the command:

```
func azure functionapp publish "<function_name>" --python
```

docs: [Azure Functions Python developer guide - Remote Build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=application-level#remote-build)

Answer (score -3):

Seems like you use the wrong command.

Have a look of this:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push#cli

The command should be:

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g <resource_group> -n <app_name> --src <zip_file_path>
```

Comment: You're just showing short-hand parameters instead.